# Can a woman tell which ovary, during ovulation, released the egg? Can she feel pain (due to follicle rupture) particular to one side?

Tags: uterus, ovulation, ovum-egg-oocyte, ovary

During ovulation, one of the de-graaf-follicles in one of woman's ovaries will rupture and release a mature egg, which will then descend through the Fallopian tubes and into the uterus, where it will implant into the endometrium, until the endometrium's lining is shed (if it's not fertilized), correct?

I know every woman is different, but is it possible for a woman to feel the rupture of the follicle/release of the egg, and essentially know which ovary contributed to that month's ovulation/menstruation? Like can she tell if it was the right or left ovary? (The ovaries switch off each month, right?) Is it common or rare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rupture of the follicle is totally painless as it is not innervated.
However, some women experience ovulation pain. It is particular to one side, and the mecanism that cause pain are not fully understood. It is maybe due to the excessive size of the follicle that stretches the ovary or to irritation the abdomen.
[On mayo clinic . com](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/mittelschmerz/basics/symptoms/con-20025507), it is said

> Mittelschmerz [middle-pain, aka ovulation pain] pain occurs on the side of the ovary that's releasing an egg (ovulating). The pain may switch sides every other month, or you may feel pain on the same side for several months.

So it is apparently possible for some woman to guess what ovary ovulated on this cycle.